# Descending order using heapq

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, heap

I am using **heapq** module of Python get data in ascending and descending order.

For **ascending**, I am using min heap and it works well as follow:

```
>>> from heapq import heapify, heappop
>>> heap = [9, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2, 7]
>>> heapify(heap)
>>> heappop(heap)
1
>>> heappop(heap)
2
>>> heappop(heap)
3
```

For **descending**, I have tried following different approaches but all of them have some drawback:

1. Using negative value as the priorirty to get reverse sort. I have to use separate list to make data reusable. If the original list is big, having copy of list is costly.

   ```
   >>> from heapq import heapify, heappop
   >>> heap = [9, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2, 7]
   >>> heap_neg = [-x for x in heap]
   >>> heapify(heap_neg)
   >>> -heappop(heap_neg)
   9
   >>> -heappop(heap_neg)
   7
   >>> -heappop(heap_neg)
   6
   ```
2. Using tuple with negative value as priority, this is also waste of space. I would not like to store list of ints as list of tuples.

   ```
   >>> from heapq import heapify, heappop
   >>> heap = [(-9, 9), (-3, 3), (-1, 1), (-5, 5), (-6, 6), (-2,2), (-7,7)]
   >>> heapify(heap)
   >>> heappop(heap)[1]
   9
   >>> heappop(heap)[1]
   7
   >>> heappop(heap)[1]
   6
   ```
3. Using key to sort in heapify is missing. Something like:

   ```
   >>> from heapq import heapify, heappop
   >>> heap = [9, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2, 7]
   >>> heapify(heap, key=lambda x:-x) # This doesn't work as heapify don't have key parameter
   ```
4. If I use, heapq._heapify_max(heap), I will have to _heapify_max after each element pop. Like:

   ```
   >>> from heapq import _heapify_max, heappop
   >>> heap = [9, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2, 7]
   >>> _heapify_max(heap)
   >>> heappop(heap)
   9
   >>> heappop(heap)  # popping without _heapify_max gives wrong result
   1
   >>> _heapify_max(heap)
   >>> heappop(heap) # popping after _heapify_max gives correct result
   7
   ```

Is there any way I can get **descending** order similar to how I got **ascending** order? :)

Comment: If you just need a specific number of the largest elements, you might try `heapq.nlargest` (there's also `heapq.nsmallest` to do what your first set of code does). This is very efficient when the number of items you care about is much smaller than the number of items in the original list.

Comment: Well, actually I am looking to implement running median. For this I need to get max in left half and min in right half quick. If I use heapq.nlargest(1, heap) again and again it will lose the charm as each operation will be O(n) Though, I know heapq.heapify(heap) with addition of new element in already heapified list will just take O(logn). I am actually looking for something similar. Pardon me if you feel I am being too nitpicky.

Comment: As you are willing to use the undocumented `max` features of `heapq` then there is a `_heappop_max(heap)` after you `_heapify_max(heap)`.

Comment: Can you show your running median code? I'm not sure how your concern about copying data in the negated values case applies when you're calculating a result on a stream of data. Surely you start with two empty heaps in that case, don't you?

Comment: @AChampion: Alas there's no `_heappush_max` so using the undocumented functions is imperfect too.

Comment: @Blckknght @AChampion We still have to _heapify_max again and again. Following is the result otherwise: `>>> heap = [9, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2, 7]
>>> heapq._heappop_max(heap)
9
>>> heapq._heappop_max(heap)
7
>>> heapq._heappop_max(heap)
3
>>> heapq._heappop_max(heap)
6
>>> heapq._heappop_max(heap)
5
>>> heapq._heappop_max(heap)
2
>>> heapq._heappop_max(heap)
1`

Comment: That code doesn't work because you *never* call `_heapify_max` on it. You need to heapify once at the start or it won't have the heap property and the other operations won't do what you want. With just one call (before the first pop), you'd get the results you expect.

Comment: @Blckknght Thank you for the answer. I actually got swayed by trying to achieve descending order so much that I lost track of my actual requirement. Starting with two empty heaps will definitely do the trick. Though I seriously feel having "key" parameter in heapify will be helpful, don't know why don't we have one yet and have to rely on tuples entries instead. Cheers! :)

Comment: @Blckknght Thank you for the answer using _heappop_max(). It is what I was looking for. Don't know how I overlooked this method even though I checked dir(heapq). Please post this answer, I will choose it as my accepted answer. This will work for getting descending order, whereas for getting running median I will have to use -ve entries starting from blank heap.:)

Comment: @Blckknght I believe `_heappop_max()` was added in 3.5 when they added the `key` and `reverse` params to `heapq.merge()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, your concerns about copying data when using negated values to flip a min-heap into a max-heap don't matter when you're starting with an empty heap and adding the values as you go. Since that's the use case when finding the running median of a stream of values, negating the values as you add them should work just fine.

Here's a running median generator I wrote just to double check that it works the way I expected:

```
def running_median(iterable):
    left_q = [] # heap of smaller-than-median elements, stored negated
    right_q = [] # heap of larger-than-median elements

    for value in iterable:
        if len(left_q) == len(right_q): # push to left_q when they're equal size
            if len(right_q) > 0 and value > right_q[0]:
                value = heapq.heapreplace(right_q, value)
            heapq.heappush(left_q, -value)
        else: # push to right_q only when it's (strictly) smaller
            if value < -left_q[0]:
                value = -heapq.heapreplace(left_q, -value)
            heapq.heappush(right_q, value)

        # len(left_q) is always >= len(right_q) so we never yield right_q[0]
        if len(left_q) > len(right_q):
            yield -left_q[0]
        else:
            yield (-left_q[0] + right_q[0]) / 2
```

The `left_q` heap stores the less-than-or-equal-to-median values. Each value is negated when it's pushed, so using the normal min-heap operations on it makes it work like a max-heap. We just need to remember to re-negate any value we take out of it, to get back to the original sign.

Answer (score 3):

There are private methods for this (tested at python 3.8)

```py
import heapq


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [1, 3, 2, 5]

    heapq._heapify_max(a)

    for item in range(0, len(a)):
        print(heapq._heappop_max(a)
```

And result is

```sh
sorted heap  5
sorted heap  3
sorted heap  2
sorted heap  1
```

---

But using of private methods maybe looks not enough correct for somebody. For this reason we can change ordering with placing your object inside modified wrapper

```py
class DescOrder:
    def __init__(self, entity):
        self.entity = entity

    def __lt__(self, o):
        return self.entity.__gt__(o.entity)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.entity)

def check_sorting(a, b):
    new_heap = []

    for element in a:
        heapq.heappush(new_heap, DescOrder(element))

    for index in range(0, len(b)):
        assert heapq.heappop(new_heap).entity == b[index]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_sorting([5, 1, -1, 3, 2], [5, 3, 2, 1, -1])
    check_sorting([5, 2, -1, 3, 1], [5, 3, 2, 1, -1])
    check_sorting([-1, 2, 5, 3, 1], [5, 3, 2, 1, -1])
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking instead for a sorted linked list in this case, I modify someone I found [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-linked-list-which-is-sorted-how-will-you-insert-in-sorted-way/) so it will insert with ascending order (I added the pop function, for some reason it wasn't in the code, but I think you may need it):

```
# Python program to insert in sorted list

# Node class 
class Node:

    # Constructor to initialize the node object
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:

    # Function to initialize head
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def sortedInsert(self, new_node):

        # Special case for the empty linked list 
        if self.head is None:
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node

        # Special case for head at end
        elif self.head.data <= new_node.data:
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node

        else :

            # Locate the node before the point of insertion
            current = self.head
            while(current.next is not None and
                 current.next.data > new_node.data):
                current = current.next

            new_node.next = current.next
            current.next = new_node

    # Function to insert a new node at the beginning
    def push(self, new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    # Utility function to prit the linked LinkedList
    def printList(self):
        temp = self.head
        while(temp):
            print(temp.data),
            temp = temp.next

    def pop(self):
        val = self.head.data
        self.head = self.head.next
        return val


# Driver program
llist = LinkedList()
new_node = Node(5)
llist.sortedInsert(new_node)
new_node = Node(10)
llist.sortedInsert(new_node)
new_node = Node(7)
llist.sortedInsert(new_node)
new_node = Node(3)
llist.sortedInsert(new_node)
new_node = Node(1)
llist.sortedInsert(new_node)
new_node = Node(9)
llist.sortedInsert(new_node)
print("Create Linked List")
llist.printList()
```

As you can see, it was just change the >= to <=, it does the job perfectly

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Damian, but I would like to use some built-in. Also, I would like to use Heap as they have O(logn) complexity to insert compared to O(n) using linked list.

Comment: @rishap have you think about in trees? orderedtreeset to be precise? there are some docs here http://knuth.luther.edu/~leekent/CS2Plus/chap6/chap6.html