# How to invert the order of elements in a heapq heap with object comparison functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, heap, python-3.6

First of all, I read this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792566/descending-order-using-heapq) but it actually doesn't include my desired approach. In addition, negating the actual values is not applicable for my use case.

Heapq Docs: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html

Assume I have a list of dataclass objects in my heap. Only the `a` property determines the order of objects.

```
import heapq
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class C:
    a: int
    b: int
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.a < other.a

l=[C(2,1),C(9,109),C(2,4),C(9,4)]

print(heapq.heappop(l)) # C(a=2, b=1)
print(heapq.heappop(l)) # C(a=2, b=4)
print(heapq.heappop(l)) # C(a=9, b=109)
print(heapq.heappop(l)) # C(a=9, b=4)
```

Now I want to have an inverted order. Therefore, I changed the line `return self.a < other.a` to `return self.a > other.a`. The result:

```
import heapq
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class C:
    a: int
    b: int
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.a > other.a

l=[C(2,1),C(9,109),C(2,4),C(9,4)]

print(heapq.heappop(l)) # C(a=2, b=1)
print(heapq.heappop(l)) # C(a=9, b=109)
print(heapq.heappop(l)) # C(a=9, b=4)
print(heapq.heappop(l)) # C(a=2, b=4)
```

The desired result should be one of the four solutions:

```
C(a=9, b=109)   C(a=9, b=4)      C(a=9, b=109)  C(a=9, b=4)    
 C(a=9, b=4)    C(a=9, b=109)    C(a=9, b=4)    C(a=9, b=109) 
 C(a=2, b=1)    C(a=2, b=1)      C(a=2, b=4)    C(a=2, b=4)  
 C(a=2, b=4)    C(a=2, b=4)      C(a=2, b=1)    C(a=2, b=1)
```

Probably, not all pairs of objects are compared by `heapq` that would explain the strange order. However, is it still possible to get an inverted order?

Do I have to provide more object comparison methods?

```
object.__lt__(self, other)
object.__le__(self, other)
object.__eq__(self, other)
object.__ne__(self, other)
object.__gt__(self, other)
object.__ge__(self, other)
```

If you have an completely other approach, do not hesitate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make `l` into a heap using [`heapify`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html#heapq.heapify)

```
from heapq import heapify, heappop
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class C:
    a: int
    b: int
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.a > other.a

l=[C(2,1),C(9,109),C(2,4),C(9,4)]

heapify(l)    

while l:
    print(heappop(l))
```

prints

```
C(a=9, b=4)
C(a=9, b=109)
C(a=2, b=1)
C(a=2, b=4)
```

Comment: But why is it working in the first case (in my question)? The list isn't ordered.

Comment: Because your example list happens to satisfy the heap invariant when `<` isn't reversed, but isn't a valid heap when `<` is reversed.  The [Theory section of the `heapq` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#theory) would be a good place to start reading, though I also recommend you actually try implementing all of the functions to understand how they work.