# Optimal way to store an element in a sorted list

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting

You maintain an array A of the list of enemies in decreasing order of their difficulty i.e., the most difficult bug will be the first element of the array. Initially, there are no bugs in the code. You are given N tasks.

**Input Format:**

First-line contains an integer N, denoting the number of tasks.

The next N lines contain one of the two types of operations mentioned below.

1. 1 P: Add a bug with difficulty P into array A.
2. 2: Sort the array in decreasing order and print the difficulty of `(n / 3)th` bug in the sorted array, where n is the size of the array A. If the number of bugs is less than 3, print Not enough enemies.

**Code:**

```
def get_index(a, v):
    lo = 0
    hi = len(a)
    if not a:
        return 0
    else:
        while lo < hi:
            mid = (lo+hi)//2
            if a[mid] > v:
                lo = mid+1 
            else: 
                hi = mid                
        return hi

t = int(input())

arr = []
for _ in range(t):
    op = input().split()
    if len(op) == 2:
        index = get_index(arr, int(op[1]))
        arr.insert(index, int(op[1]))
    elif len(arr) < 3:
        print("Not enough enemies")
    else:
        print(arr[(len(arr)//3)-1])
```

Constraints:

[image]

Getting Time Limit Exceeding error for #input 17 (Maybe it's a large input). [Here is a complete question](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/searching/binary-search/practice-problems/algorithm/victory-over-power-4a0cb459/) from HackerEarth.

How to optimize the code for large inputs?

Comment: wouldn't it be faster to append new elements and only sort the array when you get 2 as an input?

Comment: @gionni This approach will increase the time as we need to sort every time we get the 2 elements in the input(I have tried, but more test cases got time limit error).

Comment: Well, I guess it would take longer if you input a sequence of alternating 1 and 2 operations, but should take less time otherwise. Anyways I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168891/is-it-faster-to-sort-a-list-after-inserting-items-or-adding-them-to-a-sorted-lis) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Aim for some algorithmic improvements such as a lazy sort or [quick select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

Comment: Can you please implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an ideal case for using the Python [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) standard library to maintain sorted order as you add to the list without needing extra code.

Looking at the source question, The question setter:

1. Needs to clarify if the full stop is to be printed at the end of the not enough ... string.
2. Needs to mention integer division, i.e. // in Python rather than /.

## Code

I decided to **not** use stdin, that's left as an exercise for you, but the following code gives the expected output. (You might want to test it further though).

They don't say if they are allowed to be sneaky and add extra lines of input beyond the initial input line count. I decide to only read the stated number of lines - extra is ignored.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66525537/optimal-way-to-store-an-element-in-a-sorted-list/66527881#66527881
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/searching/binary-search/practice-problems/algorithm/victory-over-power-4a0cb459/
https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html

Created on Mon Mar  8 10:20:29 2021

@author: Paddy3118
"""
from heapq import heapify, heappush, heappop, nlargest, nsmallest


inp = """10
1 1
1 7
2
1 9
1 21
1 8
1 5
2
1 9
2""".strip().split('\n')

inp_gen = (line.strip() for line in inp)
line_count = int(next(inp_gen))
h = []
heapify(h)
for n in range(line_count):     # Extra lines ignored
    line = next(inp_gen)
    field = [int(n) for n in line.split()]
    if field[0] == 1:
        heappush(h, field[1])
    else:
        if (lh := len(h)) < 3:
            print('Not enough enemies')
        else:
            print(nlargest(lh // 3, h)[-1])
```

Comment: I have tried this as well, but it is giving the wrong answers. Seems like for the large length of the list it won't work as expected. I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64023962/8353711) code. Can you please add the solution in code format if possible?

Comment: Hmm, if using heapq works for small heaps. it should work for large ones too. It could be memory or time limited, but maybe add some more corner-case checks of your code for smaller sizes of list.

Comment: The same code(present in OP) worked well for all test cases except for the #input 17. I have replaced the sorting part with heapq and getting the wrong results for most of the inputs.

Comment: Added code that works for their examples and uses heapq. Note, that although h[0] is guaranteed to be the minimum value in h, you need nlargest/nsmallest for other values.

Comment: Your solution is working fine for #input 17 but for other test cases this is not working, getting time limit exceeded error. But thanks for the `heapq` method. I think the `nlargest` will take a long time for alternate 1 and 2 operations.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest *efficient* solution for this problem uses two heaps: a min-heap for the highest n/3 elements, and a max-heap for the remaining (lower) elements.

When you add an item, you need to compare it to the min element in the high heap.  If its larger, then put it in the high heap, and if it's smaller, then put it in the low heap.

Then, move an element between the heaps if necessary to keep n/3 elements in the high heap.

The add operation takes O(log N) time, and the n/3rd element is always immediately available as the min element in the high heap.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: replace list with [`collection.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque), and introduce a check to see if the new element goes at the beginning or at the end of the list. the following code passes all tests:

```
from collections import deque

def get_index(a, v):
    lo = 0
    hi = len(a)
    if not a:
        return 0
    elif a[0] <= v:
        return 0
    elif v <= a[hi - 1]:
        return hi
    else:
        while lo < hi:
            mid = (lo+hi)//2
            if a[mid] > v:
                lo = mid+1 
            else: 
                hi = mid                
        return hi

t = int(input())

arr = deque()
for _ in range(t):
    op = input().split()
    if len(op) == 2:
        index = get_index(arr, int(op[1]))

        arr.insert(index, int(op[1]))
    elif len(arr) < 3:
        print("Not enough enemies")
    else:
        print(arr[(len(arr)//3)-1])
```

Long explanation: as you may read from the comments, my first idea was to use sort, but it clearly is slower than OP solution for most cases.

I then tried to run OP solution, and saw that it failed only for #input17. Checking the input, I saw that it was the worst case for your bisection insertion algorithm, since it is just a list of increasing numbers.

This was easy enough to fix, I simply added an explicit check to see if the new element was greater than `arr[0]` or lower than `arr[hi-1]`.

Adding this by itself didn't make the algo pass the test, which at first surprised me. After a bit of investigation I understood that the problem was the insert (duh) which takes `O(n)` operations to add an element at the beginning (basically every step in test case #17). This is where `collection.deque` comes into play. Thanks to `deque`, you can insert at the beginning using `O(1)` operations (I'm sure `appendleft` is that fast and I'm guessing insert is just as fast).

Comment: Thanks. Good to know the insertion of a list takes `O(n)`. If I replaced `get_index` function with  `bisect` lib, then #input17 is accepted.